# My http listener is working in a console project but not in my test

Tags: f#

EDIT for moderators

I had this issue this morning, but the problem has been somehow solved on its own. If it were to come back and I could exactly tell what is happening I would reopen another question with more details.
Thx

I have the following code to start a http listener (I have so far copied and pasted a lot from [this series of article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297112%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) )

`httpAgent.fs` :

```
namespace Server.Core

open System.Net
open System.Threading

type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>

/// HttpAgent that listens for HTTP requests and handles
/// them using the function provided to the Start method
type HttpAgent private (url, f) as this =
  let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
  let agent = Agent.Start((fun _ -> f this), tokenSource.Token)
  let server = async { 
    use listener = new HttpListener()
    listener.Prefixes.Add(url)
    listener.Start()
    while true do 
      let! context = listener.AsyncGetContext()
      agent.Post(context) }
  do Async.Start(server, cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token)

  /// Asynchronously waits for the next incomming HTTP request
  /// The method should only be used from the body of the agent
  member x.Receive(?timeout) = agent.Receive(?timeout = timeout)

  /// Stops the HTTP server and releases the TCP connection
  member x.Stop() = tokenSource.Cancel()

  /// Starts new HTTP server on the specified URL. The specified
  /// function represents computation running inside the agent.
  static member Start(url, f) = 
    new HttpAgent(url, f)
```

`httpServer.fs` :

```
module httpServer

open Server.Core


let execute = fun ( server : HttpAgent) -> async {
        while true do 
                let! ctx = server.Receive()
                ctx.Response.Reply(ctx.Request.InputString) }
```

This code runs well in a console project (ie: I can access it with a browser, it does find it) :

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let siteRoot = @"D:\Projects\flaming-octo-spice\src\Site"

    let url = "http://localhost:8082/"
    let server = HttpAgent.Start(url, httpServer.execute)

    printfn "%A" argv
    let s = Console.ReadLine()
    // Stop the HTTP server and release the port 8082
    server.Stop()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

whereas in my test, I cannot access the server. I have even put some breakpoint in order to check with my browser if the server was up and running , but chrome tells me no host exists with ths url.

```
namespace UnitTestProject1

open System
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
open Server.Core
open System.Net.Http

[<TestClass>]
type HttpServerTests() = 
    [<TestMethod>]
    member x.Should_start_a_web_site_with_host_address () = 
        let host = "http://localhost:8082/"

        let server = HttpAgent.Start(host, httpServer.execute)

        let url = "http://localhost:8082/test/url"
        let client = new HttpClient()

        let response = client.GetAsync(url)

        Assert.IsTrue(response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode )
```

Thanks for any enlightment...

Comment: Re edit: the F# tag is reasonably quiet at some times of the day don't be stressed about not getting answers quickly.  Having said that have you tried adding a small pause before requesting the URL in the test as you may be running into a threading issue

Comment: I was thinking about that. But checking manually that the server is up and running with a browser should be enough as a pause I guess. I'll have a try anyway. In the meantime, I am trying to run it it with Nunit to check that it does not come from Ms Tests. 
And thx for the comment. I am always a bit nervous about giving enough details to engage discussion on my topic...  my bad... :(

Comment: Erf.. No more luck with Nunit. It is so strange that this code should work in a console...

Comment: Does changing `client.GetAsync(url)` to the corresponding non async method work?

Comment: Things are getting weirder by the minute... I have only changed the mstest with your advice adding "response.Wait()" but then trying the Nunit Test it worked.. I have to look a bit more at what happen exactly on my laptop.. Thanks for your help and have a nice day. I ll post another question and I can set the problem anew.

Comment: Tell me when you will have read this comment so that I delete the question, it does not make sense anymore...

Comment: Read the comment but I don't think you can delete this as it has an upvoted answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: thx John. Didn't know that rule...

Answer (score 2):

You're starting server at port **8092**, but client tries to access it at **8082**.

Comment: Nope. Thanks for pointing that out, but it does not do the trick. I was already trying the good port when browsing manually to check if the server was running after my breakpoint.